# How do I un-zoom compiz?

Tags: 10.04, compiz

I'm using a keyboard I'm not used to, and I hit Super_L instead of Alt_L when I middle-mouse-dragged across the screen.  On this Ubuntu 10.04 with Compiz, apparently, this zooms the screen to the area that I dragged across.

Now I'm stuck.  I can super-middle-drag across a bigger area, but apparently I can't quite hit all of the corners exactly because the screen still moves a bit when I move the mouse around.

How do I undo this zoom effect completely?

- This looks like "[EZoom](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Ezoom)", which says that super-"1" (default keybinding, anyway) should reset it, but that doesn't seem to work here.  Close...

Answer (score 2):

On the [EZoom](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Ezoom) page, it says that the option "Zoom Specific Level 1" sets the scale factor to 1.000, i.e., normal scale.

Thinking that this used GConf, I searched in gconf-editor, and found the key `/apps/compiz/plugins/ezoom/allscreens/options/zoom_specific_1_key` was set to "Disabled".  I changed this to `<Super>1`, and pressed super-1, and it worked!