# How do I zoom out my desktop?

Tags: compiz

I have recently updated to Version 10.4 on my Elonex webbook and now my desktop is zoomed in.

How do I zoom out?

Answer (score 4):

Zooming should be controlled by the <kbd>Super</kbd> + mouse wheel scroll combination by default. If you can scroll on your webbook by e.g. sliding your finger along the right side of the trackpad, you can try zooming back out this way.

If this doesn't work, you might have to open CompizConfig Settings Manager or gconf-editor and [tweak some of the settings yourself](https://askubuntu.com/q/82236/18612).

Answer (score 0):

Use Compiz config settings manager to find out which combination is set to zoom in and out your desktop

Comment: I recommend editing this answer to explain *how* to do that. If you include screenshots (in addition to detailed explanation), that may also be helpful.